# Update Sqlsrv32.dll

Tags: sql-server, windows, dll, odbc, windows-server

I have been looking how to update "Sqlsrv32.dll" is the driver for ODBC connection to SQL SERVER I have windows 8.1 and the version is 6.0 and I need version 10.0 because I need a connection to **SQL SERVER 2016** and the application only works with that driver.

The only way that I found is to change manually the dll, in windows 10 the dll is update and works with the connection.

Another question is If it is the same the dll from windows server and the dll from windows 8.1 because I need the connection on the windows server and want to upate it manually with the dll I got.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Were you able to find a way to update your SQLSRV32 driver?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and since no one has answered this, I'm giving my solution.
I have internal website which still uses classing ASP and it has ODBC connection to MS SQL server. The original Native client stopped working, when TSL 1.0. and 1.1 was disabled. I managed to fix it like this:
Download sqlncli.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402 and install it.
In your ASP code change connection string:

```
# Old:
"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=sql.server.local;Initial Catalog=your_database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=your_user_id;Password=your_password"
# New:
"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=sql.server.local;Initial Catalog=your_database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=your_user_id;Password=your_password"
```

[image: ODBC Native Client]